# How to find the element and click by it's value?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I am doing a python selenium web driver project. Here is a button, I tried various ways, xpath, name,value,type,link text methods but it didn't work. I even tried to click by class name, but becuase the other button comes first, it clicks on that instead. Unlucky.

```
<li class="login_button">
      <input type="button" value="Uygula" onclick="btnApply();">
      <input type="button" onclick="window.location='/index.html'" value="Atla"> #I want to click this one.
</li>
```

I got this one also, but this is completely unrelated to this code above.

```
<li><a href="#" class="edit" id="editBtn" title="Düzenle" onclick="editClick('ppp1.1', 'MyISP_PTM_35')"></a></li> #I wanna click this button.

<a href="#" class="edit" id="editBtn" title="Düzenle" onclick="editClick('ppp2.1', 'MyISP_ETH')"></a>
```

As you can see, class, id, title all are the same. I can't click based on these. It seems there is only option that I can click through MyISP_PTM_35 thing but what is that? How to reach that?

Answer (score 1):

There are three solutions that I think of immediately:

1. Find the element based on its value:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(function(el){
  if(el.value === "Atla"){
    el.click();
  }
});
```

```html
<li class="login_button">
      <input type="button" value="Uygula" onclick="btnApply();">
      <input type="button" onclick="alert('Found It!')" value="Atla"> #I want to click this one.
</li>
```

2. Add a unique class to the element:

```js
document.querySelector(".foo").click();
```

```html
<li class="login_button">
   <input type="button" value="Uygula" onclick="btnApply();">
   <input type="button" class="foo" onclick="alert('Found It!')" value="Atla"> #I want to click this one.
</li>
```

3. Instead of finding the element, just so you can click it and perform some task, just perform the task:

```js
function foo(){
  alert("found it");
}

foo();
```

```html
<li class="login_button">
      <input type="button" value="Uygula" onclick="btnApply();">
      <input type="button" onclick="foo()" value="Atla"> #I want to click this one.
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering the HTML:

```
<li class="login_button">
        <input type="button" value="Uygula" onclick="btnApply();">
        <input type="button" onclick="window.location='/index.html'" value="Atla"> #I want to click this one.
</li>
```

To click on the element with *value* as ***Atla*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css*:

  ```
  let loginButton = driver.findElement(By.css("li.login_button input[value='Atla'][onclick*='index']"));
  await loginButton.click();
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  let loginButton = driver.findElement(By.name("//li[@class='login_button']//input[@value='Atla' and contains(@onclick, 'index')]"));
  await loginButton.click();
  ```